# How do I use SharedPreferences to getString in Kotlin (android)?

Tags: android, kotlin, key, sharedpreferences

I just can't figure out how to use this a fragment. The official documentation shows this example:

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
val defaultValue = resources.getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key)
val highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue)
```

Replacing "getInt" with "getString" always returns ""

```
    val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val password = sharedPref?.getString("key", "")
    if (key == "") {
      // this always calls even when I change the value from the settings menu!
    } else {

    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you are saving and retreiving ? In the code you are retrieving `password` but checking `key` in if condition

Answer (score 3):

This is the simple class use for store any data type (`String`, `Boolean`, `Int`) in `SharedPreference`:

```kotlin
class PrefUtil(context: Context) {

    private val context: Context
    val PREFS_NAME = "my_prefs"

    fun setInt(key: String?, value: Int) {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit()
        editor.putInt(key, value)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun getInt(key: String?, defValue: Int): Int {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
        return prefs.getInt(key, defValue)
    }

    fun setString(key: String?, value: String?) {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit()
        editor.putString(key, value)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun getString(key: String?): String? {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
        return prefs.getString(key, "null")
    }

    fun setBool(key: String?, value: Boolean) {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit()
        editor.putBoolean(key, value)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun getBool(key: String?): Boolean {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
        return prefs.getBoolean(key, false)
    }

    fun getBool(key: String?, defaultValue: Boolean): Boolean {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
        return prefs.getBoolean(key, defaultValue)
    } 
 
    init {
        this.context = context
    }
}
```

and for store `String` use:

```
PrefUtil(this).setString("Key","value")
```

for getting `String` from `SharedPreference` use:

```
PrefUtil(this).getString("key")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a piece of data for this key first, and then call get method:

```
    val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    with (sharedPref.edit()) {
      putString("key", "abc123456")
      apply()
   } 
    val password = sharedPref?.getString("key", "")
    if (password == "") {
      // ....
      Log.d(TAG,"password is empty.")
    } else {
      Log.d(TAG,">>>:$password")
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not work, still returns "" and it's completely ignoring the preferences in the Settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
//For Add String Value in sharedPreferences
val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
    putString("yourStringKey", "Hello World")
    apply()
}

 //Here get enter string value from sharedPreferences other activity 
  val sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
  val string = sharedPreferences1.getString("yourStringKey", "hi") //"hi" is default value
Log.e("sharedPreferences1", "sharedPreferences1 Val is -->> $string")
```

Comment: What do I put in the "key" area?

Comment: @UndergroundDev You can Put Your Own Anything but write in `getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE)`  the same key then which you enter 1st time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I actually needed to use SharedPreferences as I'm using a Settings Activity. Thanks for the answers though as they kind of helped to lead in the direction I needed.